# Swagger plus Ocelot

Tags: swagger, ocelot

I´m trying to implement a gateway with ocelot and swagger (https://github.com/Burgyn/MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot). I was able to configure everything well in my localhost, now I need to deploy my solution to kubernetes, but,  because there are some features been developed in paralell, I was requested to deploy my solution in a subdirectory, something like this.

- https://domain/Feature1/gateway1
- https://domain/Feature2/gateway2
  ...

They don´t what to have a subdomain by feature.

My configuration works but there is a problem with swagger UI, because the test paths are maped like this.

https://domain/api/service/method

but I need something like

https://domain/Feature1/api/service/method

Is it posible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if I help, but MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot support Virtual Directory. [Please try this](https://github.com/Burgyn/MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot#virtual-directory)

Comment: HI Mino, to be more specific, the apis (downstream) are running in the root  http://localhot:5000, so, i think using  virtualdirectory doesn't apply to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could help to someone, this is the only way i could make this setup to work.

Reach the swagger docs in:
https://domain/gatewayfeature1

And the apis in:
https://domain/apisfeature1

The same for another feature.

Docs
https://domain/gatewayfeature2

Apis
https://domain/apisfeature2

I'm using nginx as reverse proxy and ocelot as gateway for my apis in and GKE cluster.

The ingress yaml that I ended using is this by feature, "apifeature1", "apifeature2",...

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: testdomain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gateway-feature1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /docsfeature1/(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: gateway-feature1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(apifeature1/.*)
```

The Ocelot Config by feature "apifeature1", "apifeature2",...

In this case I´m reading the feature name from the configuration, so the ocelot config ends like this example.

```
{
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/apifeature1/api/controller/{everything}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post" ],
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "apifeature1",
      "Port": "80"
    }
  ],
  "SwaggerKey": "api"
},
```

And the gateway by feature.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/apifeature1");
    return next();
}); 

.
.
.

app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI(c =>
{
    c.DownstreamSwaggerEndPointBasePath = "/apifeature1/swagger/docs";
    c.PathToSwaggerGenerator = "/apifeature1/swagger/docs";
    c.DocumentTitle = "DOCUMENT";
});
```

It works, but, I think it could be improved.